# How to render the Excel cells font color with C#?

Tags: c#

I need to render a color in Excel,when the cells content is equal to "true",the font color is green!When the font content is equal to "false",the color is red.This is my code:

```
private void colorRender(Worksheet workSheet)
    {
      for(int i=0;i<workSheet.Rows.Count;i++)
      {
        for(int j=0;j<workSheet.Columns.Count;j++)
        {
          if(workSheet.Columns.Name=="校验结果")
          {
            if(workSheet.Cells[i,j].ToString()=="false")
            {
              //if the cells was equal to false,set the font color red,others green. 
              //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheets.
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

When i write there and i encounter a problem:the worksheet do not contain a get_range funcion.

Comment: I presume that the commented code is where you encounter the problem? Please add the whole line of code so that we can better understand how you are using the Excel range

Answer (score 3):

You have to cast the Cell object you want to be a range, then try to set font style.

```
if (workSheet.Columns.Name == "校验结果")
{
    Excel.Range range = workSheet.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range;
    if (range.Value2.ToString() == "false")
    {
        range.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    }
    else
    {
        range.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe someone will find the [**XlRgbColor**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlrgbcolor.aspx) enumeration useful